# Why isn't the sound file not played on every new message received?

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm

I've made a messenger web application using PHP, JavaScript and Ajax. Now, I want a sound to be played on every message the user receives. For that, I've used this algorithm:

```
var sound1="";
var sound2="";
$(document).ready(function(){

    var soundvar=setInterval(soundFunc, 800);

    function soundFunc()
    {
       var chatattr4=$(".chatwindow").css("visibility");

       if(chatattr4=="visible")
       {
            sound1=$("#conversation #receivermessage").last().text();
            var soundvar2=setTimeout(soundFunc2, 700);
            function soundFunc2()
            {
                sound2=$("#conversation #receivermessage").last().text();
            }
        }

        var soundvar3=setTimeout(soundFunc3, 750);

        function soundFunc3()
        {
            if(sound1!=sound2)
            {
                var audio = new Audio('fb.mp3');
                audio.play();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

So what I'm doing is checking almost every second the last received message in two different **setTimeout**s. If it is different, the sound is played. It's working almost okay, but sometimes the sound is not played. (If you receive messages too quickly, sound won't be played on each message received, that is other case, I don't have problem with that). I don't think there's any problem with browser or sound. But I think it's problem with this algorithm. I don't want to use any other algorithm.

Can this algorithm be modified/improved/fixed so that it works better? (95-99% accuracy).

Comment: You are really doing it wrong. You should tie new messages to an event and handle that instead of constantly checking for new messages.